# How to get list of opened windows in Qt

Tags: qt

I need to handle WM_QUERYENDSESSION in my qt application. As WM_QUERYENDSESSION recieve only QApplication so I want to get list of all opened windows of my application to decide winEventFilter result. How can I get it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`QApplication::topLevelWidgets()` can provide that, [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#topLevelWidgets).